# Any IOS eqquivalient for Android's Room?

Tags: ios, swift

[Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) provides a very good abstraction over SQLite database for persisting data locally in Android devices. Is there any such equivalent in IOS? What is the preferred way to persist and access structured data (with support for indexing) in IOS?

Comment: Maybe check out CoreData - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata if it offers the capabilities you want

Comment: @ShawnFrank thank you, is this the common recommended way to store and access structured data is iOS?

Comment: I would say yes as this is a framework provided by Apple itself.

Comment: Yes, use CoreData.
Managed by Apple without use any 3rd party.

Comment: does CoreData support attaching SqlCipher as Room can?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer for OP Question itself, but at least it is a good solution to move forward and out from FMDB which is in Obj-c codespace. I am talking about GRDB: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift
This is a tool in Swift codespace for SQL operations and also it has a lot of helpful features, like Migrations and SQLCipher support.
Personally, this is a project in our TODO list to move on.
So sad, we spent a looooong time to find this project.

Comment: GRDB is great - thanks for mentioning!